# find words with capital letter as starting letter but not preceded by space

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find solution to find words in a text , must start with capital letter but not preceded by a space.
example:

```
string1 = "MynameisStuartLittle"  # expected result ["Mynameis","Stuart","Little"]
string2 = "MynameisStuart Little Junior" # expected result ["Mynameis","Stuart"]
string3 = "My name is AlphredHitchcock" # expected result ["My","Hitchcock"]

result = re.findall(r"([^ ]([A-Z][a-z]+))",string1)
print(result)
```

Other alternative solution I am thinking is that to split the text by SPACE and individually check each word with regex r"([A-Z][a-z]+)" then if if length of findall is more than 1 , then that word is eligible for my result.
I am looking for any single regex solution.

Comment: Explain what this code does, and also explain why it isn't what you wanted.

Comment: In the first example the expected result is why not `MynameisStuartLittle`? Do you want to separate at every space and capital letter?

Comment: A simples regex won't be enough given your examples. Find a good word list and work with it.
The search will be iterative, trying to match parts of the text with words in the word list

Comment: Perhaps you can look into https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, modified my question.

Comment: try using this pattern `r"(?:\A|(?<=\S))([A-Z][a-z]+)"`, the first group which won't be included anywhere will check if either it is the start of the string or the character before is not a space, then match the word

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookbehind `(?<!...)`:

```py
import re

string1 = "MynameisStuartLittle"
string2 = "MynameisStuart Little Junior"
string3 = "My name is AlphredHitchcock"

print(re.findall(r"(?<! )[A-Z][a-z]*", string1)) # ['Mynameis', 'Stuart', 'Little']
print(re.findall(r"(?<! )[A-Z][a-z]*", string2)) # ['Mynameis', 'Stuart']
print(re.findall(r"(?<! )[A-Z][a-z]*", string3)) # ['My', 'Hitchcock']
```

Comment: @SwamiViswanadh Remember `findall` returns _non-overlapping_ matches (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall). `'t'` in frond of `'Little'` is already "consumed" by the previous match `'sStuart'`. That is, after finding `'sStuart'`, `re.findall` continues its job at `'L'` right after `'sStuart'`, not seeing `'t'` (at the end of `'sStuart'`) anymore.